# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does not work in my DB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I created a table `entries` with UNIQUE KEY `title`. Now I want to execute the query `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but I get compilation errors in phpMyAdmin:

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `entriess` (`title`, `description`)
    VALUES ("TEST", "TEST")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title`=`AAA`
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *not working* ??

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I added the query in the text. As to DB, I have MySQL installed. But then I got notifications referring `MariaDB`. Just mentioning in case it might be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Change the query to

```
INSERT INTO `entriess` (`title`, `description`)
    VALUES ('TEST', 'TEST')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title`='AAA'
```

In MySQL we enclose `varchar`s into apostrophes, not into quotes.

Comment: It still doesn't work, highlighting the words ON, DUPLICATE and KEY. Also it says `MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'AAA' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Markus use `\`title\`='AAA'` instead of `\`title\`=\`AAA\``.

Comment: Lajos your anwer is correct since you pointed out the problem, but you have a typo in your query, (using `\`` instead of `'`).

Comment: @marcell great comment, thanks, didn't notice that, I thought it was an apostrophe.

Comment: @marcell: So, what should be used? `title`=`AAA` or `title`='AAA'  ?

Comment: @Markus After my previous comment Lajos already corrected the typo in his answer so you should use what is in his answer: `\`title\`='AAA'`.